# Creating polygons from gaps in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon

Using PostGIS, I want to fill a gap between other polygons.

Image to explain from where to extract the polygon:

[image]

Can you help with some directions what functions to use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `ST_Union` to aggregate the polygons into one polygon and then `ST_InteriorRingN` to get the border of the gap and `ST_BuildArea` to get polygon of the gap. If there is more than one such gap use `generate_series` and `ST_NumInteriorRings`.
Example:

```
WITH polygons(geom) AS
(VALUES (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(0, 0), 1.1,3)),
        (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(0, 2), 1.1,3)),
        (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(2, 2), 1.1,3)),
        (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(2, 0), 1.1,3)),
        (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(4, 1), 1.3,3))
),
bigpoly AS
(SELECT ST_UNION(geom)geom 
 FROM polygons)
SELECT ST_BuildArea(ST_InteriorRingN(geom,i)) 
FROM bigpoly
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,(SELECT ST_NumInteriorRings(geom) FROM bigpoly)) as i;
```

[image: example]
Blue-start polygons Purple-final polygons

Comment: This is one of those answers that is so genius, I wish I could upvote it twice.

Comment: @JohnBarça Wow, you really made my day. I used to compete with you long ago. Thanks.

Comment: I upvote for you @JohnBarça, now someone has to vote for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Jakub's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/60672/67513) does the job. In a similar approach, you could use `ST_DumpRings` to dump the interior rings, which have `path != 0`. Perhaps it can be a little bit faster for bigger tables.

```
WITH polygons(geom) AS
(VALUES (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(0, 0), 1.1,3)),
    (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(0, 2), 1.1,3)),
    (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(2, 2), 1.1,3)),
    (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(2, 0), 1.1,3)),
    (ST_Buffer(ST_Point(4, 1), 1.3,3))
),
bigpoly AS
(SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM polygons),
rings AS
(SELECT (ST_DumpRings(geom)).* FROM bigpoly)
SELECT geom FROM rings WHERE path[1] != 0;
```