# How to detect gaps in a MultiPolygon table with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a mapping of land use. In it, I need to run a topology query to detect gaps between the polygons. Is there a PostGIS function to do this?

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/60672/16594

Comment: @JakubKania. That is a good answer. Is there anything wrong with mine? As I understood it, OP wants to find the gaps and possibly the polygons adjacent to the gaps.

Comment: Do you wish just to find the gaps, or the polygons that are contiguous to the gaps.

Comment: @JohnBarça I don't know really, yours looks okay, just wanted to give more options.

Comment: @JakubKania. Sure always a good idea, I was worried I had messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a function to do this directly, but you could calculate the [difference](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html) between the boundary (or the concave hull) of your land polygons and the union of the same land polygons, which would return a MultiPolygon with all the gaps.

```
SELECT ST_Difference(
   (SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_Boundary(ST_Union(geom))) from land),
   (SELECT ST_Union(geom) from land) 
) as diff;
```

assuming that your input table is called land.

Note you have to use [ST_MakePolyon](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html) as [ST_Boundary](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Boundary.html) will return a LineString.

You could take the result of this, which will be the holes, and intersect with the original polygons, which will give you a list of those polygons that touch a gap.

```
SELECT id, geom 
FROM land l,
(SELECT ST_Difference(
   (SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_Boundary(ST_Union(geom))) from land),
   (SELECT ST_Union(geom) from land) 
) as geom) as holes
WHERE ST_Touches(holes.geom, land.geom);
```

Comment: I belive that doesn't exist, too. I searched in internet a lot and I find nothing. My hope is that someone know more than me about it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [ST_NumInteriorRings](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumInteriorRings.html) wich returns the number of interior rings (holes) or return NULL if the geometry is not a polygon.

```
SELECT 
      ST_NumInteriorRings(ST_Union(geom)) AS num_holes FROM land;
```

Assuming that your table name is *land* and geometry column is *geom*.

Answer (score 0):

Combining and slightly improving the efficiency of the above answers. Note the use ST_EXTERIORRING instead of ST_BOUNDARY for cases when you do not want any holes on the interior at all.

```
SELECT ST_DIFFERENCE(ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_EXTERIORRING(all_geometries)), all_geometries) AS gap_geometries,
       ST_NUMINTERIORRINGS(all_geometries) as gap_count
FROM (
    SELECT ST_UNION(wkb_geometry) AS all_geometries
    FROM land 

) SUB
```